# Ubuntu phone podcasts

Tags: phone

Will I be able to receive my favourite podcasts with the aquarius E4.5 Ubuntu edition phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are podcast apps (e.g. [Podbird](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.mikeasoft.podbird)) available in the Ubuntu Store, that you can download and use on the BQ Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu Edition.

I-tunes links don't seem to work directly on podbird. However, you can use [feedflipper](http://picklemonkey.net/feedflipper-home/) to convert them. I did a small experiment and it worked on most feeds.

Comment: Hi Bruni, thanks for your reply, can I get access to the apple itunes podcasts with this app?

Comment: @max see my improved answer

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Comment: ok David Ive done that